# How can I store this data in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 tables `users` `alerts` and `articles` a user can setup an alert so when a new article is added that match his profile he will get an email

I am trying to write a small code to do this task

and this is what I came up with so far

```
$query_users = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result_users = $conn->query($query_users);

while ($users = mysqli_fetch_row($result_users)) {
    $user_id  = $users[0];  
    $user_email  = $users[1];   
    $query_alerts = "SELECT * FROM `alerts` where user_id='$user_id' and active= '1' ";
    $result_alerts = $conn->query($query_alerts);
    while ($alerts = mysqli_fetch_row($result_alerts)) {

            $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$alerts[2]);
            $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$alerts[3]);

            $query_search = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `category_id` = '$category' `title` LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY `articles`.`id` ASC ";
            $result_search = $conn->query($query_search);

            $count = $result_search->num_rows;

    }
    }
```

Now what I want to do is to store the result this way

Put each alert `category` + `keyword` + `count` in an array then put it in an array that contain the user `id` and `email`

So at the bottom I can loop through the users and send to the user with id 1 and email example@website.com 
a table like this

---

Category        | Keyword      | articles count

---

Health          | Diet         |      5

---

Buisness        | Banks        | 2

---

I hope you understood my idea, I am very confused and dizzy I didn't even know what to type in the search box

Comment: So what is the question?  I'm not sure what the problem is?  You can just add the query results to an array to store them in an array by itterating over the result. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: @DuckPuncher The problem I didn't know how to store them in the data, in my head I had a logic problem and I complicated the things while the solution is only 1 line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one array outside of while and add 3 variable in array when loop is executed.

i added 2 lines in your code which are.

```
$response = array();
```

and

```
$response[] = array
(
    'category' => $category,
    'keyword' => $keyword,
    'count' => $count
);
```

Complete example

```
<?php
$query_users = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result_users = $conn->query($query_users);

$response = array();
while ($users = mysqli_fetch_row($result_users)) 
{
    $user_id  = $users[0];  
    $user_email  = $users[1];   
    $query_alerts = "SELECT * FROM `alerts` where user_id='$user_id' and active= '1' ";
    $result_alerts = $conn->query($query_alerts);
    while ($alerts = mysqli_fetch_row($result_alerts)) 
    {
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$alerts[2]);
        $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$alerts[3]);


        $query_search = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `category_id` = '$category' `title` LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY `articles`.`id` ASC ";
        $result_search = $conn->query($query_search);

        $count = $result_search->num_rows;

        $response[] = array
                (
                    'category' => $category,
                    'keyword' => $keyword,
                    'count' => $count
                );
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
```

Comment: exactly what I want, as simple as that now I added another array before closing the final barackets `$users [$user_email] = $response;`